# Issue with wp_localize_script

Tags: wp-localize-script

unfortunately I have not found a solution here and via google. I get the following error message when calling:

> **Uncaught ReferenceError:** ait_php_var is not defined
>   ../assets/js/ait_buttons.js?wp-mce-4940-20190515 line 2

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ait_load_scripts' );
function ait_load_scripts() {
    $ait_pfad = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/assets/js/ait_buttons.js';
    $ait_add_options = 'here';
    // Enqueued script with localized data.
    wp_register_script('ait_js_script', $ait_pfad );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ait_js_script', $ait_pfad );
    // Localize the script with new data
    wp_localize_script( 'ait_js_script', 'ait_php_var',
        array(
            'external_link' => __( 'External Link', 'aittec_language' ),
            'event_category' => __( 'Event Category', 'aittec_language' ),
            'internal_link' => __( 'Internal Link', 'aittec_language' ),
            'ackids' => $ait_add_options,
        )
    );
}
```

Here is the relevant (sample) snippet from the JS file:

```
// JavaScript Document //
alert( ait_php_var.ackids );
```

The file is in the correct folder, otherwise the error would not appear in line 2. The same error message also occurs when the other variable (e. g. external_link) is called in the same or similar form.
I am looking forward to any help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove trailing slash / from 3rd line.

```
$ait_pfad = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/assets/js/ait_buttons.js';
```

this should be

```
$ait_pfad = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'assets/js/ait_buttons.js';
```

**wp_plugin_dir()** function returns url including a trailing slash ("/") so you should not add it again.

Please read [wp_plugin_dir()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) function reference to learn more about this function.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. I checked it out, but it didn't change anything. The error message actually indicates that the js file is already recognized, but `ait_php_var` is not defined.